# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS back to Gnome?

Tags: debian, gnome

It has been reported that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will use GNOME as its default desktop environment, and not Unity 8 — or even Unity 7.
What will the difference be?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a major impact for most users, just choose another Desktop Environment.

I, for one, have hated Unity from day 1, but this change has 0 impact for me, because I have been using my Desktop Environment of choice ever since.

It is likely that Unity will survive and be available to install from the repositories.

You should take this news as a chance to try out some of the tens of Desktop Environments/Window Managers available on Ubuntu and most other distros.